In the presence of oxygen after performing a running race, the body works on
a-oxidizing lactic acid
b-oxidizing NADH
c-reducing pyruvic acid
d-ATP molecule decomposition

Welcome . Questions here are required to show results of prior research as described in the [help], particularly the homework policy section. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please [edit] your question with links to or references to what you've found in your search. For obvious reasons, social media posts don't count as credible sources.
